# how to add <bindings> to WCF service inside <applicationSettings>

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a **class library project** with **WCF service** references.

When I do that I see **below entries** in **app.config :**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
 </system.serviceModel>

<applicationSettings>
    <Test.Data.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Test_Data_StudentWebService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>
                 http://test.aks/StudentServices/services/StudentDataWebService
            </value>
        </setting>
    </Test.Data.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

How can I add **binding information** to this service ?

Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: I do not understand. Can't you simply copy-paste binding/client information from DLL's app.config to the host application configuration file?

Comment: Whenever I add any service those entries are created automatically under <applicationSettings>

Now if I want to add additional bindings information to the service...how do I do it ?